# Why no compiler error when I cast a class to an interface it doesn't implement?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, interface, casting, abstract-class

If I try an invalid cast from a class to an interface, then the compiler doesn't complain (the error occurs at runtime); it *does* complain, however, if I try a similar cast to an abstract class.

```
class Program
{
    abstract class aBaz
    {
        public abstract int A { get; }
    }

    interface IBar
    {
        int B { get; }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public int C { get; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        // compiler error, as expected, since Foo doesn't inherit aBaz
        aBaz baz = (aBaz)foo;

        // no compiler error, even though Foo doesn't implement IBar
        IBar bar = (IBar)foo;
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the compiler reject the cast from *Foo* to *IBar*, when it's (seemingly?) invalid?  Or, to flip the question, if the compiler allows this "invalid" cast to the interface *IBar*, why doesn't it allow the similar "invalid" cast to the abstract class *aBaz*?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Comment: This casting to an interface bit me in the butt tonight... and boy did it hurt.

Comment: You did not mark `Foo` as `sealed`. Therefore the explicit cast shall compile. There could exist a class inheriting from `Foo` which additionally implemented `IBar`. If you use `sealed class Foo`, the cast to `IBar` shall be illegal at compile-time. (In this case the class `Foo` is nested private, so even if the cast must be allowed, it is conceivable that the C# compiler could give a _warning_ (not error since the spec says the explicit conversion exists) because it can see the full scope of the nested class. But that is likely a rare case.) _Edit:_ I now see this is covered by Alexei below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to understand the inheritance system of .Net to see why this makes sense.  In .Net, a class may inherit from only one base class but may implement any number of interfaces.

```
class Program
{
    abstract class aBaz
    {
        public abstract int A { get; }
    }

    interface IBar
    {
        int B { get; }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public int C { get; }
    }

    class BarableFoo : Foo, IBar
    {
        public int C { get; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // This is why the compiler doesn't error on the later cast
        Foo foo = new BarableFoo();

        // compiler error: aBaz is a class and the compiler knows that
        // Foo is not a _subclass_ of aBaz.
        aBaz baz = (aBaz)foo;

        // no compiler error: the class Foo does not implement IBar, however at runtime
        // this instance, "foo", might be a subclass of Foo that _implements_ IBar.
        // This is perfectly valid, and succeeds at runtime.
        IBar bar = (IBar)foo;

        // On the other hand...
        foo = new Foo();

        // This fails at runtime as expected. 
        bar = (IBar)foo;
    }

}
```

In the extremely simple original example in the question, it seems like the compiler could detect that this instance of foo is never going to be castable to IBar, but that is more of a "nice to have" warning than a matter of language correctness.

Comment: +1. Also added answer that shows case when cast fails at compile time.

Comment: I would have expected that if you wanted to cast a Foo to a Bar you would have to first cast it to BarableFoo, so that it made it clear what types you were expecting

Comment: @Andy - Are you talking about that last line or the middle `(IBar)foo`?

Comment: @BitwiseMan sorry I was getting messed up. The case I was thinking of is not in your example - it 's that you can take any variable of type IBar and cast it to type Foo without a compilation warning.

Answer (score 7):

The whole point of a cast is to suppress that compiler error.
(eg, if you know that `foo` is actually an instance of a subtype that does implement the interface)

If the compiler can prove that it is impossible for the cast to succeed, it will still give an error.  (eg, if you cast to a *class* that is not in its hierarchy)

Comment: Ok ... so you're saying the compiler can prove the first cast is invalid, but not the second.  But why can't it prove the second?  Doesn't Foo (or one of its ancestors) have to be declared as implementing IBar to make that cast possible?

Comment: @McGarnagle: One of `Foo`'s descendants would have to implement `IBar` to make the cast possible, but in many cases there's no way for the compiler to know whether an assembly containing some descendant of `Foo` that implements `IBar` might get loaded.

Comment: If you write a `foreach`, no cast is needed to make bad things.
Ex: `foreach (IBar bar in fooList) {}`

Answer (score 6):

And to show that compiler is not stupid there is actulaly case when cast will fail at compile time: if compiler can prove that no other classes can derive from the class it will fail casting to interfaces at compile time:

```
sealed class NoBar
{ 
} 

struct NoBarValue
{
}

IBar noBar = (IBar)(new NoBar()); // fails at compile time
IBar noBarValue = (IBar)(new NoBarValue()); // fails at compile time
```

In first case (`NoBar`) class is explicitly sealed (and hence no derived classes can implement IFoo) and compiler knows that it does not implement `IBar` itself - hence can fail at compile time. Second case (`NoBarValue`) is similar with only difference that value types (struct) are implicitly sealed.