# Why cannot I return something of type specified in the generic type constraint but can return the same type without constraint?

Tags: c#, type-inference, return-type, generic-constraints

I have this:

```
public IClub GetTeam()
{
    return new Arsenal();
}
//compiles since Arsenal is an IClub

public T GetTeam<T>() where T : IClub, new()
{
    return new Arsenal();
}
//wouldn't compile saying "cannot convert Arsenal to T"
```

But these things work:

```
public T GetTeam<T>() where T : IClub, new()
{
    T t = new T();
    t.Sponsor = "Nike"; //since it knows T is IClub,
    return new T();     //but why the injustice to return type alone?
}
```

1. Why wouldn't the second code block compile even though return type is anyway `IClub`? Isn't that injustice?
2. I know I am not fully utilizing the potential of type constraints in above code but what is an alternative to get the code running?

Comment: Why don't you return IClub? public IClub GetTeam<T>() where T : IClub, new().

Comment: @AmitMittal thats akin to asking why don't I use the first code block. My design is pressing for that. I mean all the clubs like Arsenal inherit IClub which has `GetTeam<T>` defined on it. which I know isnt a good design. I will rethink about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because at compile time the compiler does not know whether `Arsenal` will be convertible to `T`. `T` could be another type implementing `IClub` after all. like in `GetTeam<WhateverTeam>()`. `WhateverTeam` implements `IClub`, but you cannot convert `Arsenal` to that.

You'd have to cast the result if you want your code to compile (as in Marc-André's answer), but you should rather rethink your design (also calling `GetTeam<WhateverTeam>()` would result in an exception). Making that method generic doesn't make sense if you already know which type you will return.

Comment: This exactly addresses the question!! Thanks. Sometimes I foolishly think I know more than language designers :P

Comment: Yes I know the design being poor now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

T is an unknown type at compile time and the compiler have no way to know if they can be cast from one type to another, so you much explicitly call for a cast toward that type.

```
return (T)(object)(new Arsenal());
```

This way, the compiler know for sure that Arsenal can be cast as an object, and that object can be cast as T.
You will get a runtime assert if the cast is invalid, but it will compile and work fine if it cast correctly.

Why T is unknown if you constraint it to IClub? Because any type could implement this interface. You try to return Arsenal, but another class, let's say "Car : IClub" also implement IClub. In this case, T can be Car, but the compiler has no way to prove that Arsenal could be cast into Car... Or any other class for that matter as it only knows which interface it implement, not it's real identity.

Comment: Can also use `(T)(IClub)new Arsenal();`.  I'm not sure what the relative merits are, if any.

Comment: T is not unknown at compile time, its specified its an `IClub`! That's my confusion

Comment: T implement IClub, but is NOT IClub. Therefor, the compiler cannot know if Arsenal can be cast toward that unknown type that implement IClub. Let's say Arsenal : IClub and Arsenal2: IClub. T is Arsenal2, but Arsenal cannot be cast into Arsenal2.

Comment: @dbaseman: None I would guess, might just be cleaner from a syntactic point of view. The downcast is only there to do an upcast toward T type. Since object is the root of everything, I'm used to using it.

Comment: @nawfal that issue confused me enough previously that I asked it as a separate question.  You may find it interesting:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335757/why-no-compiler-error-when-i-cast-a-class-to-an-interface-it-doesnt-implement

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras Now you make sense. But I did not see that part in the answer. Please update ur answer to reflect that. I wasn't getting ur point when you merely say `T is an unknown type at compile time and the compiler have no way to know`, because my naive question itself says more or less `T is known at compile time and why doesnt it work bla bla` :)