# Why doesn't the VB compiler catch invalid implicit conversions to an interface type while C# does?

Tags: c#, vb.net, compiler-errors

Compare this C# ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6SWb7P))

```
public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        IFoo test;
        test = new Impl();
        test = new NoImpl();                
    }
}
public interface IFoo {}
public class NoImpl {}
public class Impl : IFoo {}
```

to this VB ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wY0OpJ)).

```
Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim test as IFoo
        test = new Impl()
        test = new NoImpl()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Interface IFoo
End Interface

Public Class NoImpl
End Class

Public Class Impl 
    Implements IFoo
End Class
```

In C#, the compiler calls out the implicit cast from NoImpl as an error.  In VB, the code compiles but fails at run time.

What specific difference between the two languages/compilers causes this?

Possibly related to [Why no compiler error when I cast a class to an interface it doesn't implement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335757/why-no-compiler-error-when-i-cast-a-class-to-an-interface-it-doesnt-implement)

Comment: Is option strict turned on in the VB compiler?

Comment: @RonBeyer no it wasn't ; just add it to the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fxgMK3) and it doesn't compile anymore

Comment: When I was a VB programmer (era .NET 1.1), I religiously made sure that option strict and option explicit were turned on, otherwise these types of errors would never pop up until runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311329?wa=wsignin1.0) about `Option Strict`:

> *By default, the Visual Basic .NET or Visual Basic compiler does not enforce strict data typing.* ... In Visual Basic .NET, you can typically **convert any data type to any other data type implicitly**.

So what is happening here is the "loose" nature of the VB compiler letting things through that would fail at runtime. C# isn't so loose about type conversions, which is why it always gives a compiler error, where VB does not. Using `Option Strict` helps identify these errors at compile time instead of run time.

Without using `Option Strict`, VB will allow any conversions/casts to go through without any kind of hiccup, but narrowing conversions, loss-of-precision conversions, and completely invalid ones will present a run-time error. The link posted at the top has information on what type conversions are considered widening.

Comment: One could say it's a "shame" that it isn't `Strict On` by default but it was always critical for design team to keep backward compatibility so we're stuck with that "legacy"

Comment: I agree, it dates back to old VB programs where "programmers" would do wonderful things like `Dim x as int` and then later `x = "10"`, which the compiler happily accepted. Usually these convoluted long-winded programs were handed over to more experienced developers and option strict turned on, the compiler would just about blow up, so it was easier to leave it off.

Comment: And that specific one is (partly) why VB.Net has so bad reputation ; a choice was made to have a smooth transition from VB6 (maybe more an economic / marketing decision than a design one) and it pays the price hard now ; a problem C# don't have.