# How to instantiate a generic class with an abstract constraint in C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, type-constraints

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class ThingBase { }

public class ThingA : ThingBase { }
```

And the following generic class:

```
public class ThingOwner<ThingType> where ThingType : ThingBase { }
```

I would like to create a ThingOwner instance like below:

```
ThingOwner<ThingBase> thingOwner = new ThingOwner<ThingA>();
```

With this code, I get the following error: *"Cannot implicitly convert type 'ThingOwner(ThingA)' to 'ThingOwner(ThingBase)'"*.

I can't figure how to make it work. I know there are lots of existing discussions about generic classes and inheritance but I tried pretty much everything and I couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert derived type to its base generic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324020/cannot-implicitly-convert-derived-type-to-its-base-generic-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make use of [covariance for generic types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) introduced in C# 4.0. For this to work you need to use an interface instead of a class:

```
public interface IThingOwner<out ThingType> where ThingType : ThingBase { }

public class ThingOwner<ThingType> : IThingOwner<ThingType>
    where ThingType : ThingBase
{

}


IThingOwner<ThingBase> thingOwner = new ThingOwner<ThingA>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Covariance/contravariance is only supported for interfaces. If you need classes, then only these can work:

```
ThingOwner<ThingBase> thingOwner = new ThingOwner<ThingBase>();
ThingOwner<ThingA> thingOwner = new ThingOwner<ThingA>();
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers some explanation. While your question can be understood, think of the following:

State you have a derived class that accepts a type parameter `ClassA`. In the `ThingOwner<ClassA>` it is only allowed to add an instance of a class that is or derives from `ClassA`. When you cast that to `ThingOwner<BaseClass>` it is suddenly allowed to add an instance of `ClassB` which also derived from `BaseClass`. This can harm your program and is actually wrong. This was why they invented generics in the first place.